# Moving grid value in three dimensional grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I am trying to perform FFT calculation in 3D grid. I have mapped two objects on to 3D grid, e.g if object border map to grid point then grid value is 1 otherwise 0. Now I want to calculate correlation between two object for which I have to translate and rotate second object border in the grid. Rotation is fine but I am having trouble with translation.

Is there any easiest way so that I can translate second object.

Example:

lets say I have a 16x16x16 grid size. Both object boundaries are mapped in two grid of same size. For second object translation I have to move its grid coordinate so that its border will move along the grid. If i simply add dx, dy, dz translation then grid coordinate will change but the grid value(object boundary) will remain same. For FFT the grid value must change after translation. Need some thought in this matter.

Comment: Can you provide some example code of what your 3D grid and objects look like?

Comment: either you use dx,dy,dz for element access or you have to move the whole Voxel map by dx,dy,dz. If your dx,dy,dz is not grid aligned then you have a problem. either use li/bi/trilinear filtering to obtain aliased values (not just 0,1) or you have to regenerate the grid again with original object ofsetted by dx,dy,dz

Comment: Spektre, the grid is fixed and easy to generate. I am reading object data which are in x,y,z format. Both grid and object center is at origin. So my object grid is based on simple comparison. If gird point coincide with object then is grid value is 1 otherwise 0. Now I want to move the object in grid so that no of grid point in object grid remain same as in original grid. Regenerating grid for every translation is time consuming, specially if grid size is large.  So i was wondering of there alternative methods available to reduce the computation during the translation.  grid points value is 0.

Comment: @snoze  1. you have to add `@` before nick in the comment otherwise the person will not receive notification. 2. what if the vertex of your object is not entirely inside grid will the value be zero or something between `<0.0;1.0>` ? I am getting the impression the first one is true. in that case you can move safely only by multiplies of grid. so clear voxel map and regenerate it again with dx,dy,dz shift. (if it is faster then instead of clearing the whole thing just clear original object points) . 3 if you do not want regenerate the grid after translation what you really want?